# Convert string in python from no quote with quote

Tags: python

I have tried:

```
a = '%s' % (John)
```

and

```
a = '%s' % John
```

but its not correct.

I need this

John -> "John"

The converted "John" has double quotes.

Comment: `'"{0}"'.format("John")`

Comment: @Keatinge great, thank you

Comment: @Keatinge it works. Thank you

Comment: or `a = '"%s"' % ("John")`

Comment: Issue resolved. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> foo = '"{name}"'.format(name="John")
>>> foo
'"John"'
```

OR

```
>>> bar = '"{0}"'.format("John")
>>> bar
'"John"'
```